# Unable to create .dslr in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, drools

I am new to `Drools Rule Engine`. 
I am using `Eclipse Helios` and `Drools 5.1 runtime`.
I am able to load `.drl` file and able to run the simple rule application. Also , I am able to create `.dsl` file,however, I do not have any option to create `.dslr` file in Eclipse. 
It would be really great if someone can tell me what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question just in case someone comes to this page with same problem.

If you are using `.dslr` , you do not need to create `.dlr` . The `.drl` would be created in memory based on `.dslr` and `.dsl` . Since `.dsrl` compensates for `.drl` file, in `Eclipse`, the process of creating `.dslr` is exactly same like creating `.drl`. All you need to do is select ,`"Use a DSL"` option (Note: this would be the only extra steps)while in the process of creating `.drl` .
Below are the snapshots for the reference,

[image: Start like creating .drl file. Nothing new here.]
[image: Select "Use a DSL" in this screen. This would be the only difference]